# How to get curl headers in server

Tags: php, curl, parameters

I'm executing following code in terminal.

```
curl GET http://www.example.com/v1/users  -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -H "Authorization: 12345678"
```

How can I receive `Authorization` parameter in server side.

I tried with `$_REQUEST`,`$_GET` methods. Not worked. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try getallheaders function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function `getallheaders()` to fetch all HTTP request headers.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

And fetch result like this:

```
Array
(
    [User-Agent] => curl/7.35.0
    [Host] => 127.0.0.1
    [Accept] => */*
    [Content-Type] => application/json
    [Authorization] => 12345678
)
```

Comment: I faced another problem If my url like `curl GET http://www.example.com/v1/users?id=1&action=view  -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -H "Authorization: 12345678"`    then `getallheaders()` not giving Authorization details.

Comment: @Gowri I tried again and no problem. What are you got terminal output? By the way, command usage is  `curl  [URL...]`, you should be remove `GET`.

Comment: Can you pls let me know, how can I pass variables in POST request along with headers using -d option. I googled but only headers receiving server. Not params.

Comment: Pass query string, e.g: `curl http://www.example.com/v1/users -d 'id=1&name=Calos'`

Comment: following is my complete url but not receving.  Can you pls check. 
`curl -X POST 'http://www.example.com/v1/users' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: 12345678'  -d 'param1=xxx&param2=xxx'`

Comment: Because when you want to post data to page, the request header `Content-Type` must be `application/x-www-form-encoded` , so if you set this header content to another type, that query string will not be send. By the way, if you use `-d` param and not set header `Content-Type`, curl can automatically set to `application/x-www-form-encoded`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135360/discussion-between-gowri-and-calos-kao).